# Mounting a drive from my Synology NAS to my Raspberry pi system (Retropie): No write rights?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, raspberry-pi, nas

I have a Synology NAS.

On this NAS, there's a group and a dedicated [RetroPie](https://retropie.org.uk) user. Both the group and user have read and write rights on a specific shared drive that contains two sub-folders: `roms/` and `saves/`.

When my RetroPie starts, those two folders are mounted using the username and password and I can read from them.

However, when trying to write, it got a permission denied error.

Doing `ls -l` on the mounted folder, I got this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root
```

Executing the `mount` command, I get:

```
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=393084k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
//192.168.xx.xxx/RetropieRoms/bios on /home/pi/RetroPie/BIOS type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=Retropie,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.50.112,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

I tried a `sudo chmod` too, the command runs fine but still cannot create a file.

Here is the command I am using to mount:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<user>,password=<password> //192.168.xx.xxx/RetropieRoms/saves /home/pi/RetroPie/saves
```

What can I do to fix it ? Previously the files where on a Windows system and everything worked well. I guess the issue comes from my NAS but I can't understand how to fix it.

**Last but not least**: When trying to connect using SSH to my NAS, it works well with my admin account, but I got a permission error when trying as the RetroPie user

I guess this is related but cannot understand how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the mount command you are using is mounting the fgiles as root, which makes them readable and executable, but not writable by everyone (the third r-x).

The tmpfs is owned by user 1000 - which is often the first user of the system, and I'm guessing equates to your user account

So what we want to do is make the files "owned" by user 1000 - I think you can do it with the following variation of the mount command:

```
  sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<user>,password=<password>,uid=1000,gid=1000 //192.168.xx.xxx/RetropieRoms/saves /home/pi/RetroPie/savesqleq
```

Note the addition of uid=,gid=  (the gid = Group ID and is likely not needed, but a good idea)

**Alternative solution**

You may be able to change the permissions on the directory so everyone can access it.   This is less secure and I don't like it, but on the NAS itself you can make the files world writable.   (I don't know the Synology command/way of doing it, but under the cover it will be doing something akin to chmod -R 777 /path/to/files

Comment: The question about SSH'ing to the NAS should be a separate question, and you should probably advise us **how** you are SSH'ing to it (ie username on each side, and if you are using a password or passphrase, and the error you are getting.

Comment: And that worked.
Couldn't have find this just by myself honnestly.
Even with your explaination I still don't really understand why it cannot be simple and why the logged user didn't already owned the files he is supposed to have write access on

Comment: The "sudo" at the beginning of the line means "Do this as root" - This needs to be done as root because to make the files appear as part of the file system mount needs to interact with the kernel which has full admin/root privileges.

Comment: Are you aware you can have your Pi box automaticllay mount the NAS at startup  by adding a line like '//192.168.xx.xxx/RetropieRoms/saves /home/pi/RetroPie/savesqleq cifs  username=<user>,password=<password>,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0'   to /etc/fstab ?